# Returning previous year's data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

The below returns all values with a data type of date

```
select date_sent_to_registrations from tblquotesnew
```

How can I return just the records for the previous year. So, if I ran the query today it would return only those records in the year 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblquotesnew
WHERE  TRUNC( date_sent_to_registrations, 'YYYY' ) = ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), -12 );
```

However, `TRUNC( date_sent_to_registrations, 'YYYY' )` will not allow you to use an index on the `date_sent_to_registrations` column (you would need to use a function-based index instead) so a more efficient version would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblquotesnew
WHERE  date_sent_to_registrations >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), -12 )
AND    date_sent_to_registrations <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select date_sent_to_registrations from tblquotesnew
WHERE TRUNC(date_sent_to_registrations,'YYYY')=TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12),'YYYY')
```

If you have partition or index on that column, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblquotesnew
WHERE  date_sent_to_registrations >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), -12 )
AND    date_sent_to_registrations <  TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' );
```

Comment: This will not use indexes on `date_sent_to_registrations` and would require a function-based index on `TRUNC(date_sent_to_registrations,'YYYY')` instead.

Comment: Turn your caps lock key off before posting anything else to this website.